# How to use variable inside "Where" keyword in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter, blazor-server-side

I want to use string variable inside .where keyword to filter out some data from list or from DbSet

Here is my sample code and it's working fine

```
var logdata = DbContext.CampaignLog.Where(o => o.Id == 1));
```

but i want to write the above code like this

```
var query = "o => o.Id == 1 ||o.Id == 3";
var logdata = DbContext.CampaignLog.Where(query));
```

or

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>()
{
    1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32
};
var smallNumbers = numbers.Where(n => n < 10);
```

can i wite something like this

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>()
{
    1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32
};
var query = "n => n < 10";
var smallNumbers = numbers.Where(query);
```

Comment: Why do you want the code to be a string instead of... code?